# How is pimple in a mouth is called?

Tags: word-request

As far as I know, acne is a pimple on a face. But how is a pimple inside a mouth (on a palate or on the inner wall of a lip or cheek) is called?

Comment: "What is ... called" not "How is ... called"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not certain exactly what you are talking about, but I think you are referring to a *mouth ulcer*.

These are [small sore patches](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=mouth%20ulcer&source=lnms&tbm=isch) that can form on the gums, lips or inside of the cheeks.  There are not true pimples (which are inflamed and infected skin glands) but appear to be similar.

Answer (score 1):

Don't click on the links if you're squeamish, but [***oral fibroma***](https://www.google.nl/search?q=oral%20fibroma&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB807GB807&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjXlMLL8vHdAhXF0aQKHWzzDH0Q_AUIDigB&biw=1576&bih=870) seems to fit the bill here...

> [**Oral fibroma**](https://www.dermnetnz.org/topics/oral-irritated-fibroma/)
>    *a common benign scar-like reaction to persistent long-standing irritation in the mouth. It is also known as **traumatic fibroma, focal intraoral fibrous hyperplasia, fibrous nodule** or **oral polyp.***

All those terms are fairly well in the realm of "medical jargon", but probably most competent native speakers would be prepared to use the term ***polyp*** (normally associated with growths / defects in mucous membranes, but the inside of the mouth would normally be seen as falling into that category for this context, even if it doesn't actually produce mucus).

People who aren't particularly familiar with ***polyps*** would probably just go with the generic catch-all term ***spots***.

Answer (score 1):

A pimple is a small **[abscess](https://www.infogalactic.com/info/Abscess)** that starts in a hair follicle.  An abscess is a void in the body, filled with a bacterial infection and pus.  It typically presses against the surrounding tissue.  It can be painful and inflamed.

Abscesses can also form inside the mouth.  If an abscess becomes too big, or is in the wrong place, it can become dangerous.